# kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter on Mac OS X 10.6.7

Tags: core-audio, audioqueueservices

I am querying AudioQueueRef for kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter and code that perfectly worked on 10.6.6 now gives me just zeros in level.mAveragePower and level.mPeakPower. Is anybody aware of any changes in the OS? Can somebody point me to sample code that can verify that this is not working anymore in 10.6.7?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Code was working fine under 10.6.6 and not any more under 10.6.7. Radar time.

Comment: Sent a bug on 29-Mar-2011: rdar://9202964

Answer (score 2):

I don't have these problems on 10.6.7. Have you set the parameter

```
kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering = 1
```

when starting your Audio Queue?

Comment: Yes, I sent a bug report to Apple and they fixed it in 10.6.8 and 10.7. So, I guess this issue has been solved.

Comment: Fine if it works. But as said everything works fine in my App which is developed under 10.6.7. - strange...